# Drupal, How to change user profile html structure

Tags: drupal-6

I want to change default  user profile values to table.

Could somebody tell how can I do this?

I try create user-profile.tpl.php

But after printing $profile I am getting already formatted values (dl)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You also have access to the variable $account in user-profile.tpl.php. This will have the raw data without markup. Make sure to clear the theme cache after adding a new .tpl file.

If you have the devel module try this code inside the tpl

```
<?php

dsm($account);

?>
```

Otherwise

```
<?php

print '<pre>'. print_r($account) .'</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: I solved this problem already this way, but thanks for response. Regards